# DependencyResolver returns null in async tasks

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I tried to run this:

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ITask>();
```

In this code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
() =>
{
    var result = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ITask>();

});
```

Though it throws an null reference exception .

I know that it is another thread but I am thinking how to get dependency resolver worked in this case, or maybe I should initilize and use directly "Task" class instead of interface.

Comment: What is null in your context? variable `result`? `DependencyResolver.Current`? or does method call GetService throw a NullReferenceException?

Comment: GetService throw a NullReferenceException

Comment: I am thinking maybe in the thread I need to reinitialize everything, though it will be hard I suppose

Comment: Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: `DependencyResolver.Current` is not thread-static or context based; it's just a static/singleton. If `GetService` throws a `NullReferenceException` there is probably something wrong with your configuration. How does your configuration look like?

Comment: But it works when it is outside Task. I don't think it is because of configuration

Comment: How is the `DependencyResolver` registered? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to resolve this issue with

```
Task.Factory.StartNew
```

Though I created AsyncController and two methods as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

And now it works in async mode and IoC also works perfectly.

Hope this answer will help someone like me :)

Comment: The link is gone.